# JUnit | How to pass parameters returned from one Junit test into another JUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a junit test testArchive(). The Junit test tests the archive() method that archives a file and returns the url to it as a String. The URL is defined as an instance variable inside the Junit Test class.

```
class Prepare {    
    private String url = "";

    @Test
    public void testArchive() {
        String url = getService().archive();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendEmail() {
        getService().sendEmail(url) // Url is turning out to be null
    }
} // end of class
```

I am writing another Junit test for sendEmail() which emails the URL. But the URL is turning out to be null, though its defined as a class variable

Can you please let me know how I need to correct my Junit test for send email?

Thank you

Comment: One test should not depend on the success of another test. Set the `url` variable to something relevant in the `testSendEmail` method instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You should really not do that.

**Detailed answer:**

Unit tests (and therefore JUnit tests as well) are intended to run separately and independently from each other. Each test should check only one method, regardless of result of another method or another test. So in your case, method `testSendEmail()` should use some hard coded URL, or better few different URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that:

- Test cases should not have side effects: the `.archive()` looks like will produce side effects
- Test cases should not assume an execution order of other test cases: your `testSendEmail` seems to assume `testArchive` is executed first, which is wrong
- Test cases should not depend on external factors: the `getService` calls looks like an external (uncontrolled) factor
- Test cases should be independent and self-contained

Instead of one test cases depending on the outcome of another,
you could use a private helper method that both test cases can call.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the 2nd JUnit test and consolidated the tests into 1. Both archive and email will happen in one test.